# C# search column in a DataGridView and make that row selected

Tags: c#

I need function that I can feed a `DataGridView`, column number, and string to search for and it selects that `DataGridView` row based on the column to search in and the string to search for.  I have the base function below, just missing a chunk of code to make it work.  Thoughts?

```
public void dgvSearchSetCurrent(DataGridView oDataGrid, int iCol, string sSearch)
{
  if (oDataGrid.RowCount > 0)
  {
    bool iFound = false;
    //Search DG column and set select/set the current row
    //missing code here

    //if not found, set current row 0
    if (iFound == false)
    {
      oDataGrid.Rows[0].Selected = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hungarian notation in a type-checked language makes my eyes burn.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void dgvSearchSetCurrent(DataGridView oDataGrid, int iCol, string sSearch)
    {
        if (oDataGrid.RowCount > 0)
        {
            bool iFound = false;
            //Search DG column and set select/set the current row

            for(int i = 0 ; i < oDataGrid.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {
                if(oDataGrid.Rows[i].Cell[iCol].Value.ToString() == sSearch)
                //if(oDataGrid.Rows[i].Cell[iCol].Value.ToString().Contains(sSearch))
                {
                    iFount = true;
                    oDataGrid.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                    break; //If you want to select all rows contain sSearch, skip this line
                }
            }


            //if not found, set current row 0
            if (iFound == false)
            {
                oDataGrid.Rows[0].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That mostly did it.  Some syntax was off, but that mainly answered it.  Thank you!

Comment: If this answer really help so, accept it please,else nothing ;-)